# Run Cron at Minute 0 of Specific Hour Set

Tags: cron, cron-task

What I'm trying to do is run a Cron job at specific hours such as 1,9,13,16 but only once for each of those hours. Setting it up every few hours doesn't work for me because it needs to be at specific hours.

This is what I'm currently using but it doesn't run: `0 1,9,13,16   *   *   *`

In order to get it to run I have to use this: `0    *   *   *   *` or `*    *   *   *   *`

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean once for each of provided hour each day?

Comment: @Teoman Yep thats what I mean. For each hour (1,9,13,16) I need the cron job to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0 1,9,13,16 * * *` is a perfectly valid cron expression (I've just checked it with jailshell, although I was confident). It seems to me you have a problem somewhere else. Try settings the cron job using `crontab -e` and make a quick test with `* * * * * wget google.com` to see if it works at all.

Also here is a online cron job expression validator if you need it: http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2009/07/29/custom-validators-cron-job-expression-validator/

Answer (score 0):

1 1,9,13,16 * * *

Try minute 1 instead of 0. It works for me.

But this 0 14 * * 1-5 works for me too, or this 0 1,13 * * *.

Comment: Strange.. 1 1,9,13,16 * * * doesn't seem to work and nor does setting the minute to other numbers: 36 1,9,13,16 * * *.